# InstantiationException while using action composition in Play framwework 2.1

Tags: playframework-2.1

I'm trying to use my first Action within a controller method with Play (2.1.x) but I get an InstantiationException error that don't really helps me understanding the problem.

Here is my method declaration inside my main controller :

```
public class Api extends Controller {

  public class CORSAction extends Action.Simple {
    public Result call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
      Logger.info("Calling CORSAction for " + ctx);
      Result result = this.delegate.call(ctx);
      Http.Response response = ctx.response();
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      return result;
    }
  }

  @With(CORSAction.class)
  @Transactional
  public static Result login() {
    // .... some code
    return ok(Json.toJson(response));
  }
}
```

Where did I made a mistake ?
I use IntelliJ Ultimate Edition for coding.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found by myself, the Action Class MUST be declared in a separated file otherwise it generates an `InstantiationException`.